# Screenshot not being saved on mobile Device for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to save screenshots in Unity for mobile whenever some object appeared on the screen. It works completely fine when I run it in an emulator and also saves images. But when I run in the real device it does not save it.

```
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "_coin_" + gameObject.name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
```

I have even set permission for accessing storage in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In general `Application.persistentDataPath` returns a **folder/directory** path.

So imagine a folder path like e.g.

```
root/some/folder
```

you are now trying to write to a file called

```
root/some/folder_coin_SomeGameObject_01-16-2024_14-32-42.png
```

which you will most probably not have access writes for ;)

You will rather want to insert the according path separator (`/` in this case). But in order to generalize this more you should always stick to

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "_coin_" + gameObject.name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
```

which will use the correct path separator based on the platform on which this code is executed.

---

**HOWEVER** from [`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html):

> On mobile platforms, `filename` is appended to the persistent data path. Refer to `Application.persistentDataPath` for more information on persistent data paths.

=> You don't want to do this yourself at all - you would end up with the whole folder path twice which might very well throw another exception internally if that target directory doesn't exist (which won't be the case). You rather want to directly use e.g.

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("_coin_" + gameObject.name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
```

Comment: Thank you @derHugo but still it does not save images for mobile.

Comment: @YuneshShrestha maybe there are more issues in your code etc we can not see. I can only see the line you shared and spot the mentioned major issue there .. very well possible that this is only one of those ... See update at the bottom for another one ;)

Comment: Yeah thank you I fixed it there was problem with my code.